# Universal change of namespace across projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, refactoring

We have a solution with ca. 60 projects.

The standard we have used for namespaces is CompanyName.ProjectName.Area.VisualStudioProjectname.

Now the project has changed name.

Is there a way to change the name of the namespace across all projects, wcf services and service references?

We have ReSharper if that could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways u can achieve this result.
Beginning from ReSharper version 5.0 and above u can simply use

**ReSharper -> Refactor -> Adjust Namespaces...**

but in your situation I do not think this is what u are looking for.
There is another solution as well simply open one of your code-files select portion of the namespace u want to change hit **CTRL + R + R** and then rename. it will go through all your project files and adjust and rename new namespace.

the same result can be achieve to update them fairly quickly through the Class View window. Open class view window, click on the namespace you want to rename, hit **CTRL + R + R** and then rename.

as u mentioned you are using ReSharper so u have everything u need to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

How about a good old `Edit / Find and Replace / Replace in Files`?

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper -> Refactor -> Adjust Namespaces might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a good use for the [Block Sync Edit](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/block-edit-visual-studio-20102012.html) Visual Studio extension.